# RSA OAEP: prevention of partial decryption of ciphertexts

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, cryptanalysis

I'm trying to understand RSA encryption (as a beginner in cryptography).

1. go on this wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding
2. scroll down to the 2 numbered points: "OAEP satisfies the following two goals:"
3. The 2nd point says *"Prevent partial decryption of ciphertexts"*.

Say that an attacker attacks a an RSA crypto system that **does not** prevent the partial decryption of ciphertexts.

What happens if an attacker can decrypt a small part of a string (e.g. 2bits out of 10) using the public key? What information can the attacker retrieve from the decrypted?

Comment: Note: I've substantially edited the question above to make it at least legible. If anything is not clear, please take a look at the initial question by clicking on the time of the last edit.

Comment: Quick hint: contrast to the scheme attacked in [this reference](http://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2000/1807/18070374-new.pdf), and its reference 2.